# DataRange problem in a ListLinePlot within a Manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, manipulate

I'm trying to create a simulation of a set of lists with `Manipulate[]` and `ListLinePlot[]`. However, as my simulation starts **with** the $x$-axis pre-defined (`DataRange -> {1, 500}`), the lists behave strangely, i.e., they are not plotted as intended. The lists **do not obbey** the $x$-axis (which is correctly plotted), but instead of that they are always at the right edge of the plot.

My code is:

```
randomWalk[x_]:=Accumulate[Prepend[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], 0]]
exchange=Table[Subscript[asset, i] = randomWalk[500], {i, 1, 5}];
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[exchange[[All, 1 ;; n]], DataRange -> {1, 500}], {n, 3,500, 1}]
```

Could someone give me a hint to solve this problem?

Comment: Perhaps you mean to use `PlotRange` instead.  Try replacing your `DataRange->{1,500}` with `PlotRange -> {{1, 500}, {-40, 40}}`.

Comment: Yay! This works perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want here is `PlotRange`.  The following does what you intend.

```
randomWalk[x_] := Accumulate[Prepend[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], 0]]
exchange = Table[Subscript[asset, i] = randomWalk[500], {i, 1, 5}];
Manipulate[ListLinePlot[exchange[[All, 1 ;; n]], 
  PlotRange -> {{1, 500}, {-40, 40}}]
, {n, 3, 500, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: The only thing I would change now is to put the $y$-axis at the left side of the plot **and** use `PlotRange -> {{1, 500}, {Min[exchange], Max[exchange]}}`. Anyway, thanks a lot !!

Comment: To put the y-axis on the left you can fix it with `AxesOrigin->{1,0}`.

Comment: I've done that too! Thanks again!